I cant submit a iframe window pop up in Cypress
I am testing a endpoint made with aspx with cypress the issue appears on a popup iframe form for adding credit card info when I complete the info and hit on save buttom using of course cypress test runner this function or buttom doesnt work so I assume it looks like it's not loading the credit card library, it looks like cypress is not allowing it to load for some reason.
this cypress code represents how i go through iframe and try to submit the info for credit card form


cy.frameLoaded('#P_L_V_v224w2_t21_c0w0_NB_ITC1i0_t1_0_c0w0_0_t0_0_CreditCardControl_0_CreditCardTokenControl_0_CreditCardTokenPopup_0_CCTokenFrame_0'); // Ensure the iframe is loaded
        cy.iframe('#P_L_V_v224w2_t21_c0w0_NB_ITC1i0_t1_0_c0w0_0_t0_0_CreditCardControl_0_CreditCardTokenControl_0_CreditCardTokenPopup_0_CCTokenFrame_0').within(() => {
            // Interact with the form elements inside the iframe
            cy.get('#FieldsForm').within(() => {
                cy.get('input[name="TokenFieldsControl$CardNumberTextBox"]').type('4111111111111111');
                cy.get('input[name="TokenFieldsControl$ExpirationDate$ExpirationDate"]').clear().type('012025');
                cy.get('input[name="TokenFieldsControl$SecurityCodeTextBox"]').type('123');
                cy.get('div[id="TokenFieldsControl_SaveButton_CD"] span').click();
                
            });
        });



this is the endpoint credit card form html
<div class="dxpc-mainDiv dxpc-shadow">
                        <div class="dxpc-header drag dxpc-withBtn" style="-webkit-user-select:none;" id="P_L_V_v224w2_t21_c0w0_NB_ITC1i0_t1_0_c0w0_0_t0_0_CreditCardControl_0_CreditCardTokenControl_0_CreditCardTokenPopup_0_PWH-1">
                            <div class="dxpc-closeBtn" id="P_L_V_v224w2_t21_c0w0_NB_ITC1i0_t1_0_c0w0_0_t0_0_CreditCardControl_0_CreditCardTokenControl_0_CreditCardTokenPopup_0_HCB-1">
                                <img src="images/button_popup_close.gif" alt="Close">
                            </div><div class="dxpc-headerContent" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 24px; line-height: 10px; height: 14px;">
                                <span class="dxpc-headerText dx-vam" id="P_L_V_v224w2_t21_c0w0_NB_ITC1i0_t1_0_c0w0_0_t0_0_CreditCardControl_0_CreditCardTokenControl_0_CreditCardTokenPopup_0_PWH-1T">Enter New Card</span>
                            </div><b class="dx-clear"></b>
                        </div><div class="dxpc-contentWrapper" style="display: table;">
                            <div class="dxpc-content" id="P_L_V_v224w2_t21_c0w0_NB_ITC1i0_t1_0_c0w0_0_t0_0_CreditCardControl_0_CreditCardTokenControl_0_CreditCardTokenPopup_0_PWC-1" style="display: table-cell;">
                                <iframe src="CreditCardToken.aspx" id="P_L_V_v224w2_t21_c0w0_NB_ITC1i0_t1_0_c0w0_0_t0_0_CreditCardControl_0_CreditCardTokenControl_0_CreditCardTokenPopup_0_CCTokenFrame_0" style="border-width:0px;;"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

finally I attach part of the iframe html code of the endpoint credit card form
enter image description here
